# Easiest way to connect custom debugger to GUI

Tags: debugging

I have a custom CLI debugger for which I'm interested in a GUI. The debugger exposes an API with simple functions such as `GetMemory()`, `SetMemory()`, `GetRegister()`, `Run()`, `Stop()`, `Address2Line()` etc. through a TCP socket using a very simple protocol.

I'm looking for the easiest, fastest way of connecting it to a GUI. It seems there are many very good graphical debuggers, so after some research I think these are my best options:

- Write a GDB translator - that will act as a gdbserver on one hand, translating all requests for the debugger, and also translate all events from the debugger to gdb compatible events. Then I can use any of the many gdb front-ends.
- Write a Visual Studio Debug Engine
- Write a plug-in for Eclipse (or some other open IDE)
- Write a fresh GUI myself

So which will take the least effort / time ? Is there another way? Is there maybe a graphical debugger where I can easily define custom functions for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write an adapter so you can interact with something standard like GDB or Eclipse.  Writing custom GUI code would be a waste of effort